# How can I import math functions in CAPL

Tags: capl, canoe

I want to convert a program that simulates CAN nodes using python CAN into a CANoe simulation using CAPL. In the python sim I used numpy for math functions. How can I import statistical math functions such as standard deviation or normal.cdf into my CAPL script?

Answer (score 2):

CANoe allows you to use custom DLLs in your CAPL code (search CANoe Help for CAPL-DLL).

So, if you can re-write your Python code to work with Cython (reference: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html), you can try to create a DLL from your new Cython code and then call the exported functions of that DLL from your CAPL script.